# Giving same data parameters same instance

Tags: c#, list, iterator

I have a text file with such structure:

```
{A, B, C, D}
{B, E, D}
{C, A, F}
......
```

The first row represents a start location and the others is destinations. Forexample:

```
A -> B, C, D
B -> E, D
C -> A, F
```

I have a basic class called Location, where i save all the locations and destinations.

```
Location locA = new Location();
Location locB = new Location();
```

I'm interested in using the same instance location without making a new instance for everyone, forexample like:

```
Connection(locA, locB));
Connection(locA, locC));
Connection(locA, locD));
Connection(locB, locE);
```

The problem is when i'm splitting my text file. i'm putting the first row inside a list. and the destination in another list. :

```
DKLocations Startloc = new DKLocations();
DKLocations Destloc = new DKLocations();

List<DKLocations> DKLocations = new List<DKLocations>();
```

Here is my code so fare:

```
 foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"routes.txt"))
                {

                    foreach (Match oMatch in Regex.Matches(line, @"\{([^,]*)"))
                    {
                        ComboBox1.Items.Add(oMatch.Groups[1].Value);
                        Startloc.Identifier = DKLocations.Count().ToString();
                        Startloc.LocationName.Add(oMatch.Groups[1].Value);
                        DKLocations.Add(Startloc);

                        var dest = Regex.Matches(line, @"\p{L}+")
                        .Cast<Match>()
                        .Skip(1)
                        .Select(match => match.Value)
                        .ToList();

                        var price = Regex.Matches(line, @"\d+")
                        .Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(match => match.Value)
                        .ToList();

                        var destAndPrice = dest.Zip(price, (d, p) => new { dest = d, price = p });

                        foreach (var i in destAndPrice)
                        {

                            ListBox1.Items.Add(oMatch.Groups[1].Value + " to " + i.dest + " " + i.price + " kr." + DKLocations.Count().ToString());

                        }
                    }
```

How to give the destination same instance as the start location when splitting?

Comment: Sounds like you should store your locations in a dictionary so you can recall them as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want the "memoizing" pattern.

In C#, this is usually done with a dictionary. E.g.:

```
Dictionary<string, Location> memos = new Dictionary<string, Location>();
```

Then as you read the data, you check the dictionary first:

```
Location location;

if (!memos.TryGetValue(locationId, out location))
{
    location = new Location(locationId);
    memos[locationId] = location;
}

// do stuff with location now
```

The main thing is to have a way to identify which `Location` instance you want, and then use that as the key in the dictionary.